# Glassfish cannot start, port is occupied

Tags: java, server, glassfish, port

I tried to run my war application on port 80 instead of 8080. However when I change port number of Glassfish to 80 it cannot start because apache uses that port. My website is working on that port and I want to run my application in a subdomain of my website. What should I do to get rid of 8080 port in URL?

Comment: Questions end with a "?" on English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two applications cannot share a TCP port on different subdomains since the concept of a subdomain/domain is specific to DNS and HTTP, not TCP itself. However, you can either keep both Apache and Glassfish on alternate ports (perhaps listening on 127.0.0.1 only) and use nginx or another reverse proxy. Alternatively, you can keep Apache on port 80 and instruct it to reverse-proxy requests on the subdomain to Glassfish, or the other way around.

Comment: Can I use port 443 ?

Comment: @AhmetAy 443 is HTTPS. I would advise against it, since a user would expect http://foo.com and https://foo.com to resolve to the same site (and you'd need a certificate and everything)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your website on Glassfish. It has a built-in http server.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on server.

[image]

Click on add server.

[image]

Add glassfish server information. Click on choose. Then click on next.

[image]

After that, the created server is available under the server tab. Right click on the created server and start the server, then, create new web application.